# iOS 15 XCUITest addUIInterruptionMonitor

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

Had a few tests that broke after updating to iOS 15 and Xcode 13 because they are no longer able to dismiss alerts that pop up.

I have been using `addUIInterruptionMonitor` and had it working from the beginning of testing on my project.

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System Dialog") { alert -> Bool in
   let dontAllowButton = alert.buttons.element(boundBy: 0)
      if dontAllowButton.exists {
          dontAllowButton.tap()
      }
      return true
}

app.tap()
```

Comment: How did you fixed it?